# Awk: Create columns based on current column value

Tags: awk, columnsorting

Need some awk-fu! I have the following data structure:

```
ybcxl,05,06,07,08,09,10,11  
yxxu,01  
yxxu,03,05,06,07,08,09,10,11  
ybban,01,03,04,05,06,07,08  
zxvhu,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12
```

Each line *should* have 13 columns. Starting at Col 2, I need to asses the value. The value should always be the column number minus 1. In other words, Column 2 should have a value of  1. I need to create columns (by inserting commas) so that each line has the appropriate number of columns with the existing values ordered correctly (col number minus 1 with an offset of the 1st record).

Example of corrected data:

```
yxxu,01,,,,,,,,,,  
yxxu,,,03,,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat af.txt
ybcxl,05,06,07,08,09,10,11
yxxu,01
yxxu,03,05,06,07,08,09,10,11
ybban,01,03,04,05,06,07,08
zxvhu,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12

$ cat af.awk
BEGIN { FS="," }
{
    printf "%s", $1
    for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i) a[$i+0] = $i
    for (i=1; i<=12; ++i) printf ",%s", (i in a ? a[i] : "")
    print ""
    delete a
}

$ awk -f af.awk af.txt
ybcxl,,,,,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,
yxxu,01,,,,,,,,,,,
yxxu,,,03,,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,
ybban,01,,03,04,05,06,07,08,,,,
zxvhu,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12
```

Test to make sure that all the rows have 13 columns:

```
$ awk -f af.awk af.txt | awk -F, '{ print NF }'
13
13
13
13
13
```

Test to make sure column numbers are one more than their corresponding field value (when present):

```
$ awk -f af.awk af.txt | awk -F, '{ error = 0; for(i=2;i<=13;++i) { if ($i && i != ($i + 1)) error = 1 } print (error ? "ERROR!" : "GOOD!")}'
GOOD!
GOOD!
GOOD!
GOOD!
GOOD!
```

Explanation:

**BEGIN { FS="," }**
Set field separator to comma

**printf "%s", $1**
Output the first field (using `printf` to avoid a newline)

**for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i) a[$i+0] = $i**
Store all the numbers present in the record into an array, using their numeric
equivalents as the indices (`$i+0` converts string into number)

**for (i=1; i<=12; ++i) printf ",%s", (i in a ? a[i] : "")**
For each field we want to output, if the number is in the array print it,
otherwise, just print the comma

**print ""**
Print a newline to finish the output record

**delete a**
Clear the array before reading the next input record